# Altium Desinger: Collect harness instances into bus

Tags: altium

I'm working on a larger project involving Altium Designer 13 and Multi Level Design.
The problem: I have numerous instance of the same Harness and I want to collect them into same bus and output them trough single bus port:

[image]

When I compile the project, I get the following error:

[image]

Can anybody help me how to correct it?
Maybe, my idea was wrong to collect numbered harness instance into one bus?

Comment: I don't think you can connect harnesses through busses. But you can connect harnesses through other harnesses.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not supported by Altium Designer, only nets can be tied to a bus. Moreover you're not supposed to attach a net label to a harness, it's automatically named after its ports' name.

From [the relevant documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-obj-busbus-ad):

> A Bus is used to bundle any number of **nets**. To do this, the following conditions must be met:
>
> - Each individual net must be identified by a net label.
> - The individual nets must be named using the standard naming pattern `{Name}{NumericalIdentifer1}`, `{Name}{NumericalIdentifer2}`, for example `Address0, Address1, ..., Address n`.
> - The Bus that the individual nets join must be identified by a net label, in the format `{Name}[{StartingNumericalIdentifer}..{EndingNumericalIdentifier}]`, for example `Address[7..0]`, or `LED[1..8]`.
>
> [image: Signal harness]

But you're allowed to:

- Group several buses into a harness.
- Harness several harnesses. (theoretical, not tested for real)